# c# Socket Close , Socket Open

Tags: c#, sockets

I have a List of Sockets that are connected and live on the Form1

```
List<Socket> Clients;
```

For Example i want to Pass on of the Socket to the next Forms as:

```
Form2 F2 = new Form2();
F2.ClientSocket = Clients[2];
```

So I want to Close the Socket :

```
Clients[2]
```

and let the `F2.ClientSocket` Opened 
just like we're passing the connection from socket to socket !

Thanks for your Time !

Comment: I was following you until you started talking about closing the socket at which point you totally lost me. Can you explain more about what you're trying to do?

Comment: I want to pass the Connection between the server and the client From the socket (Clients[2]) to the next socket F2.ClientSocket

Comment: 1) No idea what "pass the connection" means. The socket represents the connection. 2) You just set `F2.ClientSocket` to `Clients[2]` so how could it be the next socket?

Comment: Lets say a Data has been sent to the Server on the Socket Clients[2] This data Will be sent on the Both Sockets For example we have a methode of check if the sent data was "Test" Show a Messagebox the Messagebox will be shown twice Cause there were 2 Sockets i want the Socket Clients[2] to  shutdown and let the connection between the server and that client on the Socket F2.ClientSocket

Comment: You can't do that because `Clients[2]` and `F2.ClientSocket` refer to the same object. If you shutdown one you shutdown the other too. Just don't read from `Clients[2]` once you pass it off. Or remove it from the list entirely since you really don't need it anymore.

Comment: Right ! Thank you so much !

Answer (score 1):

use static objects:

Form1:

```
class Form1
{
    public static List<Socket> clients = new List<Socket>();
    // your codes
}
```

Form2:

```
class Form2
{
    public Form2
    {
        var client =  Form1.clients[index];
    }
}
```